# Derivation Of The Equation Of Motion Of String from Polyakov action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory

I'm stuck at a step in the derivation of the equations of motions of a string using the Polyakov action.

In Polchinski's textbook in String Theory , Page 14 ; Equation (  1.2.25 ) ,

Varying the Polyakov action , One gets :

$\delta S\sim \int \partial _{a}(\sqrt{-det\mid \gamma\mid}\partial ^{a}X^{\mu})\delta X_{\mu} + $ Surface Terms

So $\partial _{a}(\sqrt{-\mid \gamma\mid}\partial ^{a}X^{\mu})=(\sqrt{-\mid \gamma\mid})\partial^{2}X^{\mu} + \partial _{a}(\sqrt{-\mid \gamma\mid})\partial^{a}X^{\mu}=\sqrt{-\mid\gamma\mid}\gamma^{cd}\partial_{a}\gamma_{cd}\partial^{a}X^{\mu}+(\sqrt{-\mid \gamma\mid})\partial^{2}X^{\mu} = 0$

if the surface terms vanish

Now , The Term which is proportional to the derivative of $\gamma_{cd}$ is zero in the conformal gauge. But the book did not show this. The result of the above derivative is

$(\sqrt{-\mid \gamma\mid})\partial^{2}X^{\mu}$

I don't know how to show this without using the conformal gauge.

Comment: The book does not say $\partial^2$. It must say $\nabla^2$.

Answer (score 1):

To see that the term is zero one can try to figure out that $\partial _{a}(\sqrt{-\mid \gamma\mid}\partial ^{a}X^{\mu})$ is equivalent to the covariant derivative $\nabla_a(\sqrt{-\mid \gamma\mid}\partial ^{a}X^{\mu})$, which would make the term with the metric derivative vanish ($\nabla g=0$).

A more convenient way is just to use the identity $$\nabla_a A^a=\frac{1}{|\gamma|^{1/2}}\partial_a (|\gamma|^{1/2} A^a),$$ (e.g. see [here](http://nebula.wsimg.com/390074df9fa58b7f0f0e403803a7210d?AccessKeyId=7AE175C5E3EAB003D2F4&disposition=0&alloworigin=1) for proof).

It is possible to use here $A^a=\partial^a X^\mu$ since the field $X^\mu$ is just a scalar on the worldsheet.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the last sentence is valid? Why wouldn't you be able to use that if the field $X^\mu$ were not a scalar on the worldsheet?

Comment: When I apply that identity, I get: $\partial_a((-\gamma)^\frac{1}{2}\partial^aX^\mu) = (-\gamma)^\frac{1}{2}\nabla_a\left(\partial^a x^\mu\right)$. But that's not $\nabla^2$ as it should be. What am I missing?